# Triple Equation, result not mathematical

Tags: mathematics

Originally posted on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256907/stuck-on-a-think-different-questions). This question was posted by another user on Arqade due to being a game, which is correct. However due to the lack of attention this question has garnered so far I decided to post it at the home of the puzzlers.

The issue is that the question doesn't seem to be solved mathematically, as the original poster claims the answer is **not 16**, when mathematically it should be 16.

> 3x = 24 <=> x = 8
>
> x + y = 25 <=> y = 17
>
> y + z = 8 <=> z = -9
>
> x+y+z = ? = 16

[image: Problem]

Comment: It's the HUD of the game, as you can see in this other puzzle https://lh6.ggpht.com/7bk5gEO79cW7Wlf2xve-ryRoTBVfZaHdZlz9ZmSNMbbyFGoj67sDIcXt-GBBjiIaMfk=h900

Comment: Is it something to do with the colours(red for positive integers, grey for negative?)

Comment: How do we not know the shapes have been reversed and therefore the numbers as well? Its impossible to tell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of 16, suggested as incorrect in the question, is the solution - I entered it into the app and it passed.